# How to Dynamically Generate JSON Form Objects in an HTML File?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I have an HTML form that contains a drop-down list and a div. I also have several JS files, each containing a JSON Form object created using JSON Form (link: https://github.com/joshfire/jsonform).

When I select an option in this drop-down list, I'm looking to do the following:

```
1. Determine the appropriate JS file based on the option's value.
2. Create an HTML DOM Script object using the JS file as the source.
3. Insert the script object at the end of a list of scripts located elsewhere on the HTML file.
4. Insert the JSON Form object listed in the JS file into the div.
```

When I select another option in the list: it should do the following:

```
1. Remove the previous script object and thus remove the JSON Form object.
2. Repeat the first four steps with a different JS file.
```

The code I have seems to accomplish the first three steps in the first process, but can't seem to accomplish the fourth. I am also currently unclear how to accomplish the first step in the second process.

Any help in any of these areas would be greatly appreciated.

My current code:

***HTML***

```
.........

<div class="form-bottom">
    <div class="form-group margin-bottom-none">
        <select type="text" name="selections" class="select" id="selections" style="overflow: scroll;">
            <option value="option0">------Select One------</option>
            <option value="option1">A</option>
            <option value="option2">B</option>
            <option value="option3">C</option>
            <option value="option4">D</option>
            <option value="option5">E</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group" id="target"></div>

........

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>

<!-- minify later -->
<script src="js/jsonform.js"></script>
```

***JS***

```
function myFunction() {

    var option_value = document.getElementById("selections").value;

    var js = document.createElement("script");

    var last_script = document.getElementsByTagName("script").length - 1;


    if (option_value == "option1") {
        js.src = "js/option_folder/option1.js";
    }

    js.id = "added-json";

    console.log(js);

    $(js).insertAfter(document.getElementsByTagName("script")[last_script]);

}

$("#selections").on("change", myFunction);
```

*UPDATE*

option1.js:

```
$('#target').jsonForm({
    schema: {
      input1: {
        type: 'string',
        title: 'Input #1',
        required: true
      },
      input2: {
        type: 'string',
        title: 'Input #2',
        required: true
      },
      input3: {
        type: 'string',
        title: 'Input #3',
        required: true
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you share a js file which has the schema for the form ?

Comment: Alright, I've edited the post to include what would be on one of the js files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE 1--

The library doesn't seem to be updated for the latest version of jQuery. You will need to stick with the one it supports. Working [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/jiZXMq2waGpOJzdVUqlw?p=preview)

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.3.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

---

Given that you have `jQuery` you can use `$.getScript()`

While I haven't used the library  you can load the script in this way.
You might have to apply/run the jsonForm function, but not fully sure. Let us know.

```
function myFunction() {
    var myJSForm = 'js/option_folder/' + $('#selections').val() + '.js';
    $.getScript(myJSForm)
    .done(function (script, textStatus) {
        console.log(script);
        console.log(textStatus);
        //$.loadTheForm();// not required
    })

    .fail(function (jqxhr, settings, exception) {
        console.log(jqxhr);
        console.log(settings);
        console.log(exception);
    });
}

$(function () {
    $("#selections").on("change", myFunction);
})
```

option1.js:

```
$('#target').html('');//Clear the form
$('#target').jsonForm({
    schema : {
        input1 : {
            type : 'string',
            title : 'Input #1',
            required : true
        },
        input2 : {
            type : 'string',
            title : 'Input #2',
            required : true
        },
        input3 : {
            type : 'string',
            title : 'Input #3',
            required : true
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I just tried this code out and it says "Uncaught TypeError: $.loadTheForm is not a function(…)". When I removed said function (since you said it might be unnecessary), I got a warning "jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of null TypeError: Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of null" and an error "jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of null(…)".

Comment: Yeah, JSON Form not being compatible with the latest version of jQuery is a definite problem. I was able to get the Plunker code working just by swapping JSON Form out with jQuery.dForm (link: github.com/daffl/jquery.dform), which is up to date. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: @Alexander awesome